# How to setup zend auto complete in NetBeans on Ubuntu

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, autocomplete, ubuntu-11.04

I was stuck in setup Zend auto-complete code in NetBeans 7.1 on Ubuntu 11.04

A little help would be great !

I set in Tools->Options->PHP->Zend

/usr/bin/zf.sh as Zend script
,  pressed "register Provider"  and restart NetBeans, I thought it would be enough.

But when I create simple form class, the auto complete doesn't work(simple example is below):

```
class Application_Form_AddIp extends Zend_Form {
    public function init(){
          $ip = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("ip");
          $ip->  // THERE I SHOULD GET AUTO COMPLETE-THE LIST OF POSSIBLE FUNCTIONS
    }
}
```

Does NetBeans have auto-complete like this example, and is it work on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the Zend Framework into your includes on your project. Auto complete works very good with Netbeans altough under ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: for some reason I set that on: (php_path)php/PEAR
instead of  /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php

Now everything works! Thanks

Comment: If you don't have the 'Include Path' and 'Important Files' folder, probably you have existing project and you need to register current project as a ZF project. So, juct create a ZF project with the same name of your existing project and done.