# Zend Framework 1 ACL: allow all and deny some

Tags: php, zend-framework

## Problem

Hi, I'm new to the Zend Framework 1 (I know there's a version 2 but we need to work with version 1 for this project) so don't know if this is a stupid question or not. Besides that I found it quite hard to find good documentation about registering and login-in I managed to have a system with ACL and Auth that works okay-ish atm.

I'm just wondering about my ACL if I'm doing things right.
This is what my class looks like now:

> class bckstg_Acl extends Zend_Acl {
>       public function __construct()
>       {
>
> ```
>     $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'));
>     $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'), 'guest');
>     $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'), 'user');
>
>     $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('error::error'));
>     $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth::login'));
>     $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth::register'));
>     $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth::logout'));
>     $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('data::render'));
>     $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('index::index'));
>     $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('admin::index'));
>     $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth::noauth'));
>
>     //$this->allow('guest', 'error', 'error');
>     $this->allow('guest', 'auth::noauth');
>     $this->allow('guest', 'auth::login');
>     $this->allow('guest', 'data::render');
>     $this->allow('guest', 'index::index');
>     $this->allow('guest', 'auth::register');
>     $this->allow('user', 'auth::logout');
>     $this->allow('admin', 'admin::index');
> } }
> ```

## Question

I noticed if I don't add a new controller to resources none of the 3 user types (guests, user or admin) can see the page. But I was wondering if there's a way to say that all users can see everything in general? Because basically I only need to deny the guests the 'like' system of my app and users and guests the admin panel, besides of that they can see all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize your ACL if you detect particular controller(s) or module(s)

My way for that is to ask in front controller plugin if I need to setup ACL, so:

```
// Register ACL plugin if is admin module
if($request->getModuleName() == 'admin'){
    $auth    = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $acl     = new My_Acl_Acl();
    $front   = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new My_Plugin_AclControl($auth, $acl));
}
```

For rest web site(default module) ACL is never asked for permission, only for admin module.

You have a lot of literature on the Internet, but this blog has helped me a lot in the beginning  http://www.amazium.com/blog/label/zend_acl/page/1

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this one out later. Didn't knew you could do it this way! Thanx for the literature as well, seen some interesting things on it already!

Comment: This works brilliant btw! If someone ever needed this: I used getControllerName to point to the controller. Thanks again!

Comment: I advise you to turn on auto-complete for ZF, IDE like NetBeans have that option. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7487737/949273